# Update odoo module from command line

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Please, I need help, I am trying to update my module list in Odoo 11 from the command line.

I try these three commands:

==> `-c ./etc/odoo-server.conf -u module_name -d database_name`

==> `./odoo.py -u module_name`

the solution in this link: https://gist.github.com/holdenrehg/9fd3f8596611bbfc45aea13d6315d4f4

but nothing has worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to update my module list"? This command is update a module for a specific database. In the first command there could be something within the config file, which is blocking. The second command can't work because you need to specify a database with `-d` while using `-u`. The linked command looks good to me.

Comment: i mean update apps list

Comment: And why do you need to update the modules/apps list by command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd odoo-server/

./odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf -d data_base_name -u module_name
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Update Apps List" button triggers creation of a "Module Update" wizard. The wizard has a button, "Update", which runs the `update_module` method. The only important thing that `update_module` does is to call `update_list` against `ir.module.module`.

You can simulate this via shell with the command below, but I'm not sure there's a way to do it directly from the command line in an automated way.

```
self.env['ir.module.module'].update_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please move to the location where odoo-bin exist and use the below command

```
./odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf --db-filter='data_base_name' -u module_name
```